# woocommerce product option and single-product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add 3 checkboxes to the product page which are product options such as assembly, gift wrap & accessories.  I want these to be assigned to the single product.

For example if i'm on a single product page underneath add to cart the customer can check these options.

I know of `add_to_cart()` but that adds single products to cart i want these options to be linked to the current product?

What is the correct way of doing this? at the moment i can't update woocommerce, so the plugins that accomplish this use functions not available in woocommerce 2.0

Comment: You should try [this](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/) it allows you to do what you describe

Comment: I purchased but i don't think it is compatible with woocommerce 2.0.  Are there any references to this plugin being compatible with woocommerce 2.0?

Comment: It should be compatible as its an official Woo product, have you seen the [documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-add-ons/)? Should help you.

Comment: thanks i just checked the changelog and it clearly says WC2.0 compatible... i hope this is the case as updating woocommerce is a hassle.

Comment: Good Luck :) if it works let us know.

Comment: There's a lot of goodness in WooCommerce 2.3, so I would advise updating once you've tested the upgrade on a staging server. WooCommerce 2.0 is pretty out of date.